# Why we can't use console.write or console.writeLine in class without Method

Tags: c#, oop

Can anyone please tell me the reason that why we can't use **Console.WriteLine** in Class without Method. I am trying to do this but complier is putting a error. I know its wrong but just want to know the valid reason for that .

```
 public  class AssemblyOneClass2
    {
       Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Comment: It is a statement, not a declaration.  And therefore must be written inside of a method.  Basic language syntax requirement.  And pretty necessary so the CLR knows when it is supposed to execute that code.

Comment: I am agree with you Hans ,  Writeline is a static method of Console Class.  But i am still in confusion about the reason behind that.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not using `WriteLine`. You can't put **any** code there other than declaring member variables (and properties events etc) or functions. Code like calls to `WriteLine` belongs in the body of those functions. As for the reason, when would you expect that code to run? I expect you can't answer that and neither can the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

A method is a code block that contains a series of statements. A program causes the statements to be executed by calling the method and specifying any required method arguments. In C#, every executed instruction is performed in the context of a method.

Therefore must be written inside of a method. otherwise CLR  don't know when it is supposed to execute that code. This is basic for C#.

Comment: If  i have a class  and i am creating instance of it in another class. Why i am not able to access it member variables without method ?

Comment: different question. And you can if they're public. I think you need to rewind a bit to how classes work in C#

Answer (score 1):

Class encapsulates constructors, functions, fields and properties. Accordingly, you can only write any code statement in a function or constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class AssemblyOneClass2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```

You need an actual method for anything to happen. The above snippet shows the correct way to run `"Console.Writeline("");"`

Answer (score 0):

Because `Console.WriteLine("");` can't be (or) is not a member field for the said class `AssemblyOneClass2`.

To say little more; You define member field (Data member and Methods) while defining class in order to give some behavior to that class and what all action it can perform.

For example: `Student` class having `Name` and `City` property

```
Class student
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string City {get;set;}
}
```

Just by having a call to `Writeline()` method in your class; what behavior you are defining, you think?

Even if you, keep the class declaration empty saying below, it still make little sense saying that; no behavior to the class have been defined yet and it's just kind a stub right now.

```
 public  class AssemblyOneClass2
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I believe is memory is only assigned when you create an object of the class you have created, so let us imagine that we are allowed to write a Console.WriteLine(); in the class.
Now imagine you want to execute that line from the main function now.
How are you supposed to call it? Think....
usually, it is Obj.<Method/function/datamember>.
How will the compiler get to know that it has to execute the Console.WriteLine(); in the class.
So, in order for the compiler to execute that line it has to be a part of something which has been assigned memory and can call be called from the instance of the class ,i.e the object that we have created.

I hope I am making some sense here.